# creating objects using binding <xsd:any> to xml is giving null?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to create objects using  binding data from xml file to classes which has generated from schema file xsd but it is giving null.

**here is my xsd , from which I have generated my java classes :**

```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

     <xsd:element name="people">
        <xsd:complexType>
           <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element ref="employee"/>
               <xsd:element ref="customer"/>
           </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>

      <xsd:element name="employee">
     <xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:element ref='name'/>
                     <xsd:element ref='country'/>
              </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

       <xsd:element name='name'>
               <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/'/>
                   </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>

       <xsd:element name='country'>
             <xsd:complexType>
                 <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/'/>
                 </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>

       <xsd:element name="customer">
            <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref='cname'/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>

       <xsd:element name='cname'>
             <xsd:complexType>
                     <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/'/>
                     </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

**My XML File:**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <people>
           <employee>
              <name>John</name>            
              <country>India</country>
           </employee>
           <customer>
              <cname>steve</cname>            
           </customer>
       </people>
```

**and here my code which trying to bind xml data to java objects , but giving null:**

```
 File file = new File("D:\\file.xml");  
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.jaxb.xmlbinding");  
 Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  People element = (People) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  
 System.out.println(element.getEmployee().getName().getAny()); //giving null
```

**could somebody please help me  ....**

Comment: @Grzegorz Grzybek : added xml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   <xsd:element name='name'>
           <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/'/>
               </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

means that element `name` may contain any XML **element**. No wonder you're getting null, because XML contains **text** content.

One solution may be to change schema to this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="people">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="employee" />
        <xsd:element ref="customer" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="employee">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref='name' />
        <xsd:element ref='country' />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name='name'>
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/' />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name='country'>
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/' />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="customer">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref='cname' />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name='cname'>
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/' />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

(mind `mixed="true"`). This way you'll get:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "name")
public class Name {

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;
```

instead of:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "name")
public class Name {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object any;
```

and after unmarshalling, you'll get:

[image: Eclipse's debug view]

EDIT: case when changing XSD is not an option

This is valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/namespace/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
  <employee>
    <name>
      <p1:a>x</p1:a>
    </name>
    <country>
      <p1:a>x</p1:a>
    </country>
  </employee>
  <customer>
    <cname>
      <p1:a>x</p1:a>
    </cname>
  </customer>
</people>
```

Then after unmarshalling you'll get:

[image]

Comment: **@Grzegorz Grzybek :** Thanks for giving this solution. but can we do this without modifying schema because actual requirement is like that we must not change schema ?

Comment: In that case, you're XML is not-valid: - cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'country' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'country' is not complete. One of '{WC["http://www.w3.org/namespace/"]}' is 
  expected.

Comment: **@Grzegorz Grzybek :**  Could you please tell me what would be the xml file in this case ?

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzGrzybek Is there any solution apart from this? I don't want to change my schema.

Comment: @Apoorva - can you change your XML (not XSD) as I've described?

Comment: That is also not possible. I want to achieve this by modifying JAXB bindings or either by customizing the JAXB.

Comment: You can also try transforming your XML using XSLT.