# XSD:anyType to java Object

Tags: java, xsd

I have an xsd as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="exampleDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="payload" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="message" type="tns:message" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

However when I try to get the payload value from java it returns null. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating objects using binding <xsd:any> to xml is giving null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239385/creating-objects-using-binding-xsdany-to-xml-is-giving-null)

Comment: A [mcve] would include your Java code.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The XSD uses "anyType". I tried unmarshalling . It is still returning null. Am new to this. Can you please provide me with a working example?

Comment: I'm having the same issue ;-(  In JBoss, JAX-B is unmarshalling the XML and the values null but if I change it to just an "Object" instead of the class that JAX-B is trying to unmarshal to - I see that there is a value.  Rather a pain.  I'll let you know if I figure out a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue recently, below is the workaround:

XSD:

Java Code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new XmlToObject().getClass().getClassLoader();

File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("myXmlFile.xml").getFile());

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyPojo.class);

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

MyPojo myPojo = (MyPojo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Object check = myPojo.getCheck();

if (check instanceof Node) {
    ElementNSImpl checkElement = (ElementNSImpl) check;
    System.out.println("check=" + checkElement.getTextContent());
}
```